# Creating a "box" environment in python for optimization

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, optimization, multidimensional-array

I am currently working on a project related to space optimization.

The project is basically arranging a set of objects within a box to use the least amount of space. I have the object's dimensions, surface area, volume, shape, etc. (units are originally in meter)

The problem now is that I need to create a three dimensional box container to hold a certain number of objects where i can track the coordinates if they are filled out by an object or not. Say 'object 1' fills out the corner of the box so it fills coordinates [0,0,0] to [150,150,150]

Note that i converted meter to millimeter, so when i put them in a 3D array i can disregard the decimal of the dimensions (minimize the inaccuracy). I tried using a three-dimensional array for the box but a problem arises when its dimensions is too big. so a box of 1x1x1 meter is equivalent to 1000 x 1000 x 1000 millimeter which leads to a memory error

is there any alternative in creating such "box" environment that my algorithm can operate on in python?

I tried matplotlib's pyplot 3d but i cant track the coordinates and give a specific length,width,height to the plot since it was really meant for plotting data, not storing them.

Comment: you could use binary dtypes to encode open/filled more compactlyas individual bits

Comment: For e.g. boxes or circles (spheres) we can write no-overlap constraints [2d example](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/07/rectangles-no-overlap-constraints.html).

Comment: There should not be any memory error from within matplotlib due to simply multiplying the units by 1000. But I think the question is pretty unclear about the problem itself.

Comment: @f5r5e5d the issue about binary dtypes is i wont be able to track which object filled that specific coordinate range. a character maybe? but i believe python doesnt have a character datatype

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, there's no error in matplotlib. the error was using numpy's 3d array. the thing about matplotlib is i wont be able to distinguish what object filled that specific point/space in the plot.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen my problem really is creating the box container to hold all objects or in your answer "sub boxes" and since i'm dealing with 3D objects, a 3d array is also needed which is my problem (due to memory error)

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting this. But the resolution is pretty independent of the units. I mean you can use millimeter as units, but choose a 10 millimeter resolution, hence use a 100 x 100 x 100 which should not lead to memory errors.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes there is no debate that it wont lead to a memory error and how i can just use millimeter as a unit. the problem is distinguishing which group of points belong to a certain object since im plotting several objects within a box.

Answer (score 1):

So i got this idea from @f5r5e5d where in creating numpy 3d arrays, i specify the dtype.

since i need a box with atleast 1000 x 1000 x 1000 cells, and assuming a box can hold by average 100-150 objects, therefore i will only store unsigned int from 0 to 150.

so in creating my array i can just do

```
box = np.zeros((1750,1750,1750), dtype = 'u1')
```

where u1 is an 8bit unsigned integer.

gives memory error when i go beyond 1750 but for a box with 1billion or more elements, works perfectly!